# How to integrate Office 365 REST API into my Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, httprequest, office365

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app, and I'd like to integrate some Office365 features.

For instance I would like to book a meeting room, create an event in a calendar, or display a meeting rooms calendar (for availability check).

I found this [get a calendar view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#Getevents) Office365 REST API but I dont understand how to use it.

I understand that I have to send a GET request (formated as explained in msdn.microsoft.com) with Rails, but I don't understand how to deal with the Response. How can I retrieve the response, put it into a hash and display the information formated into my own Rail view ?

Any tutorial, examples, or more explanatory doc than the (hardly readable) MSDN documentation would be much appreciated.

Comment: mm couldn't you do a sample curl and get the response back to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/ruby. It parses the JSON response into objects (using `JSON.parse`).

Comment: Great ! This tutorial is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a gem that is good at making and parsing HTTP requests; something like https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

This is assuming you are making your requests server side. I would probably create models which correspond to the Office365 objects you want to model in your own app.